# Expresso store : add on, hook store_order_complete_end creates order id+1

Tags: expresso-store, add-on-development, hook, orders

Expression Engine 2.10.1 , Expresso Store 2.5.1

For enabling payment via Klarna we have used following Hook to create a custom add-on to handle order creation via API.

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html
store_order_complete_end

The API connection is succesfull however after order completion we get some strange behavior:

An order ID is created, but after the hook is called the order ID get +1 on the order id (e.g original order 451 becomes order 452).

Answer (score 1):

Using `$this->extensions->last_call` in the hook turned out to be redundant.